# Expression returning List instead of Array

Tags: scala

When I do **str.split("\|")** by default it returns `Array[string]`. How do i get return type as `List[String]` instead of `Array[string]`. I was able to convert to List using `toList`. But, I was wondering is it possible to get it without `toList`.

```
scala> val str = "a|b|c"
str: String = a|b|c

scala> val arr = str.split("\\|")
arr: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)

scala> val convList = arr.toList
convList: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val lis: List[String] = str.split("\\|")
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
found   : Array[String]
required: List[String]
val lis: List[String] = str.split("\\|")
```

Comment: what is the problem with toList? Remember, String is the java.lang.String and its split returns an array.

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually there were lot of array in full program but every where i wanted it to be List.  Implicit conversion seems helpful

Comment: But implicit conversion is just syntactic sugar. It is still an array and you still call toList :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an implicit conversion, then assignment will work without type error;

```
implicit def arrayToList[A](arr: Array[A]) = arr.toList
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Implicit conversions are a bad idea in most cases (they now require a feature flag), and this conversion specifically is likely to make it much harder to reason about performance in your program. Just use `toList`, possibly via a helper method wrapping `split`.

Comment: Thank you for bringing out, can you give a detailed link for further readings? @TravisBrown